# British National public Art Gallery High Quality Images for GAN Modelling

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images, deep-learning

Looking for a [British National public Art Gallery](https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/) with high-quality images, to train GANs for Image Regeneration.

Answer (score 0):

[National Gallery, London](https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/)

The National Gallery is the primary British national public art gallery, sited on Trafalgar Square, in central London. It is home to one of the world's greatest collections of Western European paintings. Founded in 1824, from an initial purchase of 36 paintings by the British Government, its collections have since grown to about 2,300 paintings dating from the mid-13th century to 1900, most of which are on display.

[Download from here](https://the-eye.eu/public/Images/National%20Gallery%20Paintings/)

This directory contains 2,405 items.

```
wget -m -np -c -U "eye02" -w 2 -R "index.html*" "https://the-eye.eu/public/Images/National%20Gallery%20Paintings/"
```